# SQL SERVER Verifying mirror status from 2 weeks ago

Tags: sql-server

How we can verify if the mirror was working fine two weeks ago ??

I was checking the sqlerror log, I'm not sure whether the mirroring sync status will be logged, if so, I don't have that log. because the log was reinitialized. we do take backups. So, my other question is what to restore from tap backup to retrieve error log ( is it master db, or msdb )?

Your help is appreciated!!

Comment: You may have already checked this, but, while in SSMS>rt click db>tasks>Launch DB mirroring monitor>history ellipses looks like you can go back as far as 1000 records.  Does this show you anything you can use?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how long your SQL Server logs are retained, you can filter the SQL Server Logs with "mirror" to get an overview (not every detail) of the mirroring status on your Mirror server.

You will see messages like:

> ```
> Database mirroring is active with database 'Name' as the mirror copy.
> Database mirroring is inactive with database 'Name' as the mirror copy.
> ```

And some other messages as well that may reveal other issues on the mirror server such as:

> ```
> The mirroring connection to "serverconnection" has timed out ...
> ```

Comment: Thanks Rob, I know it stays in SQL error log, but we do have a job backing up our master and msdb. Now, which one of these two dbs will have the sql error log in it.. so i can retrived the backup, and check the error log ?

Comment: @Nick - I was referring to the SQL Server Error Log, which you can access from SSMS at *Management\SQL Server Logs\Current...* through the oldest SQL Server Error Log on your machine.  For my server, that ran back about 5 months, but it depends on how often you cycle your Error Logs.  (This has nothing to do with the "transaction log" which is restorable as part of a database restore.)  The log files can, in my install be found at: D:\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log

Comment: Rob, Thank you again, I do understand the difference between errorlog, and t-log.. my question is if the error log is cycled, how and where i can look at them..

Comment: @Nick - I showed where my log files are in the server I used.  If the error logs are missing for the date you want to check, then you will have to see if the files that contain the error logs can be restored for you to examine.